# how to use Store procedure under Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5

I had imported SP functions with EF model successfully,but couldn't find c# function into context. weird! Anyone had some issue?

Answer (score 1):

Function import not worked for me neither. You may write your execute method or best solution might be (if not neccessary) convert it to Entity Framework 4 and your method will be there for you.

Answer (score 0):

Importing stored procedure through wizard is not enough. You must open model browser and [add function import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for that stored procedure.

Comment: Trust me, I do. But couldn't find out my SP function in EntityConext.Now I had to use EntityCommand to call it,but looks very weird, it's .net 3.5 bug?